# Getting staking accounts of wallet

Tags: web3.js, staking

I want to receive all staking accounts for a wallet.
How can I do this? I'm trying to use getParsedProgramAccounts, but don't know what should I put for data size and offset

```
 const accounts = await connection.getParsedProgramAccounts(
      STAKE_PROGRAM_ID,
      {
        filters: [
          {
            dataSize: 200, // number of bytes
          },
          {
            memcmp: {
              offset: 64, // number of bytes
              bytes: WALLET_KEY, // base58 encoded string
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

`dataSize` here seems redundant. And for offset you should use 12

Result:

```
const accounts = await connection.getParsedProgramAccounts(
      STAKE_PROGRAM_ID,
      {
        filters: [
          {
            memcmp: {
              offset: 12, // number of bytes
              bytes: WALLET_KEY, // base58 encoded string
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. Where did you get the offset of 12 from?

Answer (score 1):

Staking account is a Token Account so you can use the "getTokenAccountsByOwner" from Solana JSON RPC call :
https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettokenaccountsbyowner

Comment: After call I recieve exception: failed to get token accounts owned by account F8dQyDCkxKtgoNi8QGJ2qyDGcRnzzy15BzmCb4JoPdaR: Invalid param: unrecognized Token program id
    at Connection.getTokenAccountsByOwner

programId is Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111


getTokenAccountsByOwner(new PublicKey('F8dQyDCkxKtgoNi8QGJ2qyDGcRnzzy15BzmCb4JoPdaR'), {
        programId: new PublicKey(
  'Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111',
),
      });